# Restore the app from file in C:\ProgramData\Qlik\Sense\Apps folder after reinstall Qliksense server

Tags: business-intelligence, qliksense

After changing host name, I got some issue to access QMC and Hub address of Qliksense, then I uninstall and re-install Qliksense server after backup C:\ProgramData\Qlik\Sense\Apps folder.
How can I restore all apps in that folder to new server Qliksense? Files in this folders is not *.qvf, then I cannot import them via QMC, I tried to copy them to new C:\ProgramData\Qlik\Sense\Apps folder, but it didn't work.

Comment: Rather post your answer as an answer, and mark it as the accepted answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the solution: just rename and add extension (.qvf) to the files and import via QMC